# Is advanced formatting supported for a DataGridView's TopLeftHeaderCell?

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, datagridview

My DataGridView's `TopLeftHeaderCell` value displays information about columns and rows like this:

> Date \ Value

Is there any better way to display this information? For example, I'd like to have a line from top left to bottom right corner of the cell and have "Date" and "Value" words on each side of the line. Is anything like that possible?

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example (a table, picture etc) how this diagonal line should look like?

Comment: I imagined it something like this:
http://s18.postimage.org/kl68cfkd5/matrix.png

Comment: Thank you for the picture. No, out of the box the DataGridView does not support this. However, you can create a user control which renders that and adds it as a picture.